# How to import jar file in maven

Tags: java, maven-3

I am creating a maven project. I have a folder named *project* and under this folder I have pom.xml which is the parent pom, app, model and service folder. These folders are also maven project. I run clean install on service and works fine because it has no dependency to other module. Then I clean install model and it says cannot find symbol class CustomFileReader. This class is in the service module and I am using it in model module. My question is how can I use this class and what is the right import statement. After building the service module, I have now service-1.0.jar under target folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add service module as dependency for model module. Edit pom.xml file in model module, like this

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>sevice-grouop-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can use any classes in model from service.